# D7 module for payment associated to a node?

Tags: views, 7, commerce

I am looking for a D7 module that will allow users to make a payment that is related to a node. So let's say I have a content type called 'Events', and have lots of nodes in the 'Events' content type, I want users to be able to pay in order to attend one of these Events. So maybe the user would view an Events node, and then they can pay for the node (not to view it... but pay for what the node is offering: e.g. an event)

Anyone know of anything??

I don't want to use Drupal Commerce because I don't want a shop per se, I just want to take payment related to a node.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options. Drupal Commerce is obviously really powerful, but if you want something light take a look at the Drupal [Pay](http://drupal.org/project/pay) module. It is pretty light weight and integrates with webform and a number of other modules.

Comment: Well... I installed Pay and it was horrible. Broken features and no updates for 4 years or something. But I tried the Payment module, which is much better and has a module for webforms integration too... so thanks for pointing me in the right direction I guess

Comment: Oh gosh, sorry to hear it sucked, but I'm glad you found a better option.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use the ubercart module. When you create a Event, you create a product (can be done automatically  with rules). On each event page you show a block of the corresponding product. You disable in the store and cart section most things and you have a lightweight shop/solution.